# Method for Finding Minima: Squaring Functions to Simplify Differentiation

Tags: calculus

Lately, I've been tackling calculus problems and stumbled upon a technique that I'm unfamiliar with. In certain cases, when seeking the minimum of a function, it seems possible to square the function if it involves a square root term. This manipulation makes differentiation more straightforward and aids in determining the minimum. However, I lack a comprehensive understanding of this technique.

Specifically, I'm currently working with the function

$$f(x) = \sqrt{a^2 + x^2} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{b}{x}\right)$$

While I can directly find the derivative of this function, it appears that squaring the function first and then differentiating it simplifies the process of finding the minimum.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me to resources or explanations that would help me grasp this technique better. I am particularly interested in understanding why squaring the function facilitates the task of finding its minimum.

Comment: It's a simple trick. If $\psi$ is strictly monotone, then $\psi (f(x))$ and $f(x)$ have the same minimizers. Assuming your function $f(x) = \sqrt{a^2 + x^2} \cdot \Big(1 + \frac{b}{x}\Big)$ is non-negative for $x$ in your domain, then you are applying the strictly monotone transform $\psi: \mathbf{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbf{R}_+$ to your objective function. For details, see Boyd-Vendenberge: Convex Optimization (p.131, Transformation of objective and constraint functions).

Comment: It's useful when the original objective $f(x)$ is not smooth. Applying an appropriate $\psi$ can make it easier to differentiate. The classic example would be least squares: minimize$\|Ax - b\|_2 = \sqrt{(Ax - b)_1^2 + \dotsb + (Ax - b)_m^2}$. Squaring both sides gives you a quadratic function, which is easier to deal with than the original objective.